# How to totalize positive and negative numbers

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me how to totalize/Collect positive and negative numbers in javascript? What metodes shud I use

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking. Could you edit your post with an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @tseiv is my answer what you wanted? I can change it if required?

Comment: @shash678 Thank you very much, it help me better understand problem i wanted to solve. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some useful methods could be **[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** and **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** assuming you are referring to an array of numbers that you want to totalize [sic] (I assume you mean sum):

```js
const nums = [5, 3, -2, 0, 9, -8, 7]

const positiveNumsTotal = nums.filter(num => num > 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
const negativeNumsTotal = nums.filter(num => num < 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
const overallTotal = nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

console.log(`nums array: ${JSON.stringify(nums)}`)
console.log(`Postive number total: ${positiveNumsTotal}`)
console.log(`Negative numbers total: ${negativeNumsTotal}`)
console.log(`Overall total: ${overallTotal}`)
```